# Array increment syntax

Tags: java, arrays

```
static boolean permutation(String s, String t){
    if(s.length() != t.length()) return false;
    int [] letters = new int [128];
    char[] s_array = s.toCharArray();
    for (char c: s_array){
        letters[c]++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i< t.length(); i++){
        int c = (int) t.charAt(i);
        letters[c]--;
        if ( letters [c] < 0 )return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

So this code snippet is from Cracking the Coding Interview and I was wondering what the  letters[c]++ and letters[c]--  means.

Is that the same thing as letters[c++]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`letters` array is used to counting how much each letter in those two strings `t` and `s` has been repeated

each char has [ascii-code](http://www.ascii-code.com/) so in this `for-each` loop , `c` convert to its ascii code , actually it casts from `char` to `integer` so it will be a `index` and `ascii-code` is unique for each character

in this statement `letters[c]++;` consider `char c = 'A'` so `c` is `65` according `ascii-table` , and in letters array `65th element` will increase once, so until now we have one `'A'` in our `s` string, and when loop ends we had counted repetition of each letter in string `s`.

```
for (char c: s_array){
    letters[c]++;
}
```

and other loop is similar , but it uses string `t` characters and for each character in `t` decreases once from it's repetition in string `s` to determine `permutation of s and t`

hope you understand what i said !

and for this question!

> Is that the same thing as letters[c++]?

no they are different.consider `char c ='A'` this statement that you said will increase repetition of `character B` because `ascii code of B` is `66`.

Answer (score 2):

> So this code snippet is from Cracking the Coding Interview and I was wondering what the letters[c]++ and letters[c]-- means.
>
> Is that the same thing as letters[c++]?

No. `letters[c]++` is equivalent to

```
letters[c] = letters[c] + 1;
```

and `letters[c]--` performs

```
letters[c] = letters[c] - 1;
```

while `letters[c++]` is equivalent to,

```
letters[c] = letters[c];
c = c + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's incrementing and decrementing values from the letters array. c is the index of the letters array you are incrementing; therefore letters`[c++]` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that the same thing as letters[c++]?

Not even a little bit. :-) `letters[c++]` in those places would be a syntax error (since Java doesn't allow arbitrary expressions as statements), since it would be `letters[c]; c = c + 1;`

`letters[c]++` is effectively:

```
letters[c] = letters[c] + 1;
```

E.g., it's *increasing* the value in `letters[c]` by one. It's not changing `c` at all.

`--` works the same way, just decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case are the same at this:

```
  letters[c] = letters[c] + 1;
```

And

```
  letters[c] = letters[c] - 1;
```

Because letters is an array of integer.
But doesn't make sense when you use the `++` or `--` operators on a value(when you have ex: an array of String).

Comment: `letters[c]++` and `letters[c] = letters[c] + 1;`  are same ! because `letters[c]` is an integer and we can use ` ++ or -- ` with an integer

Comment: In this case yes but in general when you have an array of STRING NOT